# How to create the Item node for Product Feed Submission on MWS?

Tags: xml, feed, amazon-mws

Goal:
Complete Submission for `_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_` Feed with the alternative ‘Item’ (reference Item.xsd) field included and not ‘Product’, because we are attempting to post a product within the Industrial and Scientific Category. See page 34 of https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl.pdf.

Our problem/issue:
However we are receiving feed submission warnings and errors. The major issue is that these errors and warnings seem to be invalid. When attempting to troubleshoot by comparing them to the existing Item.xsd file it seems that I am including all required properties with there correct data types.

---

An Example Feed Submission
Id: RandomForStackOverFlow 
Action: `SubmitFeed` 
FeedType: `_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_`
Failing XML Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><Header><DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion><MerchantIdentifier>RandomForStackOverFlow</MerchantIdentifier></Header><MessageType>Product</MessageType><PurgeAndReplace>1</PurgeAndReplace><Message><MessageID>1</MessageID><OperationType>Update</OperationType><Item><sku><value>PWML1000</value></sku><MarketplaceData market_name="A MarketName"><contribution_margin delete="true"><value currency="USD">10</value></contribution_margin><msrp delete="true"><value currency="USD">10</value></msrp><offering_can_ship_in_original_container delete="true"><value>true</value></offering_can_ship_in_original_container></MarketplaceData><DescriptionData><bullet_point><value>Features a high-performance permanent neodymium magnet, strong in magnetic pull and light weight</value></bullet_point><bullet_point><value>"V" style design can lift round steel objects like steel pipes</value></bullet_point><bullet_point><value>3:1 safety factor, it has high safety performance and higher efficiency</value></bullet_point><bullet_point><value>The magnetic lifter can be used to lift steel sheets, blocks, rods, cylinders and other steel materials</value></bullet_point></DescriptionData></Item></Message></AmazonEnvelope>
```

---

A primary example of what seems to be an invalid error

```
 object(stdClass)#54 (4) {
          ["messageID"]=>
          string(1) "1"
          ["resultCode"]=>
          string(5) "Error"
          ["resultMessageCode"]=>
          string(4) "5000"
          ["resultDescription"]=>
          string(427) "XML Parsing Error at Line 2, Column 877: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'bullet_point'. One of '{new_in_this_version_bullet_point, can_be_giftmessaged, can_be_giftwrapped, ean, ean8, gtin, isbn, ItemDimensions, item_name, item_weight, manufacturer, offering_condition, offering_subcondition, package_weight, part_number, product_description, product_tax_code, upc, volume}' is expected."
        }
```

From my understanding this error indicates that the `bullet point` field should not exist and I should be using `new_in_this_version_bullet_point`, or that I have some form of improper data. But there is no  point of reference to correct the error because `new_in_this_version_bullet_point` does not exist in Item.xsd. Again I have been debugging this for a while and I believe that the current Item.xsd is invalid http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/Item.xsd.

If there is any info that can help me when it comes to constructing the `Item` Node for MWS
it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After sometime, it is easier to just use the new SP-API